Error Publishing to Nexus from Jenkins: PluginClassLoader Issue
I'm encountering an error while trying to publish artifacts to Nexus from my Jenkins pipeline.
The error message is:
PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps
Here is the exact output 
I’ve ensured that all plugins are up to date, validated my Jenkinsfile, and checked network connectivity to Nexus. Despite these efforts, I still face this issue. Has anyone experienced something similar, and how can I resolve it?
PS:I tried to troubleshoot with chatgpt but nothing seems to work

Screenshots are less helpful than you might think. Can you copy and paste (formatted) the job log?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
